# Angular 6+ custom back navigation with managing history

Tags: angular

I have the following issue with browser's history.

I hit back button in my app and then I 
`this._router.navigate([...` Which is wrong because then I have in the history page I'm on as well as the page I navigated from. Then when a user hits the native back button he ends on a wrong page.

**I changed it to**

```
this.location.replaceState('xxx');
this.router.navigate(['/xxx'], { skipLocationChange  : true });
```

That does just half of the trick because when I use the back button in the app, I navigate to the page and when I use native back button nothing happens because I have it there twice.

Any I idea how can I remove one more state from history?

Comment: You need to execute `this.location.replaceState('xxx');` after you have navigated to that page. That way you will "replace" it in history.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should import `Location`:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

Then in constructor:

```
constructor(        
        private _location: Location
    ) { }
```

In your code when you want to go back you can simply do:

```
this._location.back();
```

Or if you want to skip some history you can do:

```
window.history.go(-2);
```

This one will do two times back, like you have pressed back button twice.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to not go back, go to location of my own choosing but delete two previous steps in history. So it actually behaves like a back button.

Comment: I have the same use case as @vmachacek; the idea here is you go from a>b>c then click something to bring you to a, I don't want navigating back to go to c.

Comment: @Jessycormier then after you navigated to c simply execute `replaceState` for that c URL, or you can use Angular replaceUrl: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl